# Whats the correct way to translate a "dynamic" string in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, translation

To allow the internationalization of a Python plugin for [QGIS](http://ww.qgis.org/), I'm using `QCoreApplication.translate()` like this:

```py
message = QCoreApplication.translate('Multipart split',"No multipart features selected.")
```

How can I prepare a dynamic string, like the following,

```py
message = "Splited " + str(n_of_splitted_features) + " multipart feature(s)"
```

to translate, without the need to break each of sub-strings, like this

```py
message = QCoreApplication.translate('Multipart split','Splited ') + str(n_of_splitted_features) + QCoreApplication.translate('Multipart split', 'multipart feature(s)')
```

which does not appear to be the best option.

I have found that in C++ using the `tr()` with `.arg()`, one can do this:

```c
statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Host %1 found").arg(hostName))
```

But I was unable to replicate using Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `format` command on the result of the `tr` method :

```
statusBar().showMessage(tr("Host {0} found").format(hostName))
```

The translation in the `ts` file should also contain the `{0}` string.

Edit: with Python 2.7 (and Python 3 obviously), you can simply type `{}` without the `0` if you appear to have a single argument. As Cecil mentionned, keep the numbers with the `{}` to deal with internationalisation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunatly the tr method is not recognized thats why I'm using the QCoreApplication.translate(). I will try to use {} and format in it.

Comment: "...you can simply type `{}` without the 0." **No. Never do this.** Arguments intended for internationalization should *always* be explicitly numbered (e.g., `{0}` rather than `{}`). Why? Because non-English languages may interpolate arguments in a different order, in which case implicitly numbered `{}`-style arguments would *not* be translatable. For a real-world example demonstrating this difference between two English and Norwegian sentences, see [*"Using Numbered Arguments."*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-numbered-arguments)

Comment: This is also the way how QGIS does it, e.g. in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b4613b98397a08a054ee712292c15b84e08621b1/python/user.py#L50 or in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b4613b98397a08a054ee712292c15b84e08621b1/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/BasicStatistics.py#L194 (albeit without numbers but they are single arguments).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself, maybe it's useful for someone else.

```
message = QCoreApplication.translate('Multipart split', "Splited %d multipart feature(s)") %(n_of_splitted_features)
```

Comment: Some years late -- your answer is *almost* what @Frodon suggested, which should have been accepted. In fact, if you follow the [coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), you should use his suggestion, like so: `message = QCoreApplication.translate('Multipart split', 'Splited {0} multipart feature(s)'.format(n_of_splitted_features))`.

Comment: Indeed. Many years later my python skills have improved a bit, and now I'm able to recognise what you say. Thanks. Justice has been done.

Comment: Actually, this answer is arguably the preferable solution. Why? Because `QObject.tr()` is broken by design whereas `QCoreApplication.translate()` is *not*. Riverbank themselves [strongly recommend](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/i18n.html#differences-between-pyqt5-and-qt) usage of the latter: "The PyQt5 behaviour is unsatisfactory and may be changed in the future. **It is recommended that `translate()` be used in preference to `tr()`.** This is guaranteed to work with current and future versions of PyQt5 and makes it much easier to share message files between Python and C++ code."